# Telerik Grid dynamic column names and values are not displaying from the Datatable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, telerik, telerik-grid

My Code:

```
  @(Html.Telerik().Grid<System.Data.DataRow>()
            .Name("reportsGrid")
                    .ClientEvents(events =>
                    {
                        events.OnDataBinding("onDataBinding");
                    })
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ReportsGrid", "Reports", new { _query }).Enabled(true))
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        columns.Bound(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
                    }
                }
            })
```

My Controller Code:

```
[GridAction]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ReportsGrid(string query)
        {
            var reportService = new ReportService();
            System.Data.DataTable dt = reportService.ExecuteQuery(query);
            if (dt != null)
                return View(new GridModel(sample(dt)));
                //return View(new GridModel { Data = sample(dt) });
            else
                return View(new GridModel { Data = null });
        }


        private IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, Object>> sample(System.Data.DataTable dt)
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, Object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, Object>>();
            Dictionary<string, Object> row = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
                foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            return rows.ToList();
        }

        public ActionResult ReportsGrid()
        {
            var reportService = new ReportService();
            //System.Data.DataTable dt = reportService.ExecuteQuery(query);
            return PartialView("ReportsGrid", new System.Data.DataTable());
        }
```

My Telerik Grid is displaying empty without Grid Column names and values. Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult ReportsGrid()
{
    var reportService = new ReportService();
    //System.Data.DataTable dt = reportService.ExecuteQuery(query);
    return PartialView("ReportsGrid", new System.Data.DataTable());
}
```

this controller method returns you empty datatable without any column. So this code:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
{
    columns.Bound(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
}
```

will not iterate (Model.Columns is empty enumerable).
To solve your problem, you need to initialize datatable with columns.

If you have dynamic datatable you should get list of columns in method `ActionResult ReportsGrid()` by another query.

Comment: How to initialize. Columns are dynamic and we get from the Datatable. Please Help.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to know what your query reportService.ExecuteQuery(query) will return (what columns). By the way, could you describe what do you want to show in your grid? What this codeline 'return View(new GridModel(sample(dt)))' should do?

Comment: 'return View(new GridModel(sample(dt)))' returns datatable values. Thanks.